# Changing program flash memory address for S32K312 target

Tags: c, embedded, linker-scripts

We had the application up and running fine on NXP S32K312 target when the program flash address was 0x00400000.

When we needed to change the program flash address to start at 0x00440000 in the linker file, the application was running for the first time, but then when we tried to do a reset, it showed the below message:
"Break at address "0xfffffffe" with no debug information available, or outside of program code."

Have anyone faced this issue before? and if so, what was missing?

Comment: How your micro can know that it has start from that address?

Comment: Can you show the relevant part from the linker script? Which compiler is it? "Break at address "0xfffffffe" with no debug information available, or outside of program code." sounds like the vector table didn't get properly programmed or such.

Comment: Also did you roll out your own CRT or are you using a pre-made one? Because all the relevant init code needs to be executed and some tools might make assumptions about addresses etc in the CRT that aren't true any longer, unless you find some way to tell it that addresses were changed.

Comment: @Lundin FFFFFFFs instead vector table are causing such problems. He simply moved the code & vector table to the new address expecting micro to boot

Comment: @Lundin usually pre-made CTR code is compiled with the project for those targets. Having them in somewhere in the library would not make too much sense.

Comment: @gulpr Yep, I programmed a lot of Freescale/NXP before they went haywire with their tools and support. Usually their linker scrips names the entry point to the CRT as the reset vector from the linker script. If you roll out your own one, you need to replace the name with your own reset vector. Similarly, they might have some segment called `.startup` where the CRT gets allocated.

Comment: And more often than not, you have to roll out your own reset vector because the people who writes start-up code for MCUs don't always understand beginner-level stuff like: I really, really like to run the slow start-up code on my preferred fast external quartz and not the default kitchen sink one. And I really want the watch dog to be enabled in case the CRT itself goes bananas, or otherwise why include a wtd hardware in the MCU to begin with. Explaining such very basic stuff to silicon vendors is like talking to a wall...

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply change the address in the linker script. It will not work.

Cortex-M7 uCs require a vector table at the beginning of the memory chosen for boot (using pins or OTP registers). The first position is an initial value of the SP register, the second one is the reset handler (+many other).

[image]

If you want to move your code to another address in the memory you still need to have the vector table at the beginning of the boot memory.

You need to write the bootloader which will be placed at the beginning of the flash and it will set the new vector table address and jump to your app.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Now I had the bootloader starts at address 0040 0000h, where it validates the application image flashed, and then jumps to the application, which starts at 0044 0000h.

The jumping itself happened and it jumps directly to the first line of the main application, but then it goes to Hard Fault, and I'm not too sure why this is happening.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: @MohamedNASSAR it should not jump to the `main` function only (the absolute minimum) 1. Set the new vector table 2. assign the stack pointer with application one and 3. jump to the application reset handler function.